# delete .mp3 files from player - have tried 'del d:\*.mp3' and 'chkdsk d:\ /f'

Tags: command-line, file-management

I bought a cheap .mp3 player from a guy, you know how it goes... Anyway, I tried to delete the .mp3 files from the player through the Windows folder. I kept getting an error - something about Explorer.exe and running chkdsk. So open a command-prompt, tried `del d:\*.mp3` - nothing, tried `chkdsk d:\ /f` - still nothing.

Yes, the player was recognized as d:.

I was able to view the 'files' in the command-prompt, just not nuke them.

All of the files have a 0 size, and they all have multiple instances.

I'm afraid of simply wiping the drive (even if I thought I could) because it appears to be an older player and am not sure if I could find the firmware to reformat it.

Cheap, yes, but money, still. And this looks like a fun project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the MP3 player provide a built-in tool/option to wipe the drive clean? It might also help if you could mention what MP3 player it is, and what kind of "drive" (micro-SD, etc.) you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

Some players look for each mp3 file in drive (treating ".trash" or "Recycle Bin" as any other directory).

If you previously tried to delete them from GUI, they may end up in some "Recycle Bin" directory. I will run Ubuntu from LiveCD to see the drive content from non-windows system.